# Codomain of a restriction

Tags: functions, definition

I was reading the post [Is there a name for when we extend the codomain of a function? (sort of like the opposite of the restriction)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215052/is-there-a-name-for-when-we-extend-the-codomain-of-a-function-sort-of-like-the) and have a similar question, however more simple and surely less interesting: What is the codomain of a restriction?

I mean, if I have the function $f:U\to V$ and $A\subset U$,

> the restriction is the function $f|_A\to \square$ (I mantain the $V$? I've said a professor writing $f(A)$ as codomain, but so every restriction is surjective?)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restriction of a function still has the same codomain.  So, if $f:U\to V$ and $A\subseteq U$, then the restriction $f|_A$ is a function $A\to V$.

Of course, you can always shrink the codomain to any set which contains the image, and people usually don't bother to give the resulting function a separate name.  So, if you take $f|_A$ and change its codomain to just $f(A)$ to get a function $A\to f(A)$, that function will commonly also be referred to as $f|_A$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you once again.