# What does "$\,g=f|Y\,$" mean, where $g$ and $f$ are functions and $Y$ is a subset of the domain of $f$?

Tags: functions, notation

> What does "$\,g=f|Y\,$" mean, where $g$ and $f$ are functions and $Y$ is a subset of the domain of $f$?

Comment: The restriction of $f$ to $Y$, usually

Comment: An addedum to answer bellow, about the codomain of the restriction: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395543/codomain-of-a-restriction. Good studies!

Comment: Is it written $f|_{Y}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f|Y$ means the restriction of $f$ to $Y$. For example, the restriction of $y=x^2$ to $x\geq 0$ gives you the "right half" of the parabola.

Comment: Minor addition: it's also frequently written as $\left.f\right|_Y$.